# Join 2 Select Statements Together With Different Where Clause & Use in While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 select statements but I need to retrieve two sets of dates from one query so I can do a while loop and return the two dates in each row.

Statement One:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CREATED_BY, a.IBLOCK_ID, a.NAME, b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID,
b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, b.VALUE 
FROM b_iblock_element a INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property b 
ON a.ID = b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID WHERE b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '133'
```

Then the second one is the same but with a different where clause:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CREATED_BY, a.IBLOCK_ID, a.NAME, b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID,
b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID, b.VALUE 
FROM b_iblock_element a INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property b 
ON a.ID = b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID WHERE b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '134'
```

The b.VALUE field returns the start date when IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID is 133 and the end date when it equals 134.

I have read that I could use a CASE or UNION but unsure how this would work.  I'd obviously user b.VALUE as STARTDATE and b.VALUE as ENDDATE but not sure how to join these together.

Then I will use PHP to loop results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"QUERY");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need neither `CASE` nor `UNION`. All you need is another `INNER JOIN`. Here is joined query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.CREATED_BY, a.IBLOCK_ID, a.NAME, b.VALUE as startDate, c.VALUE as endDate
FROM b_iblock_element a INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property b 
ON a.ID = b.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID AND b.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '133'
INNER JOIN b_iblock_element_property c 
ON a.ID = c.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID AND c.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = '134'
```